# Can't deploy Google Assistant on my Raspberry pi 4

Tags: google-cloud-platform, raspberry-pi, google-oauth, google-assistant-sdk

I'm trying to follow google's tutorial to install Google Assistant on my raspberry pi 4. I'm following the steps indicated in this page : https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/guides/service/python?hl=en

When coming to launch google-oauthlib-tool to get credentials, I've made some modifications to the original script to change the port number to 8182, since google assistant's default port is 8080 and it is actually used on my raspberry.

I then launch this command :

```
google-oauthlib-tool --scope https://www.googleapis.com/auth/assistant-sdk-prototype       --save --client-secrets client_secret_xxxxxxxxxxxx.json
```

The script returns a link to link Google account, which is normal, but when clicking on "Continue" after logging in with Google, I'm being redirected to localhost:8182 but it can't be reached. I don't know what I'm doing/understanding wrond, I've followed every step on the tutorial

Answer (score 0):

This is a [similar problem as I posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76010014/google-oauthlib-tool-doesnt-ask-authorization-code-and-has-no-headless-opti). I couldn't reach the localhost but I didn't change the port number like you. I solved the problem by realizing the google assistant SDK guide assumes you are running on a headless client (OS without GUI) but, if you are using a version of your OS **with GUI**, the `google-oauthlib-tool` assumes you are running it from the device itself, not over ssh.

So instead of using ssh to connect to the rpi, the problem was fixed for me when **running this tool from the command line on the GUI** of the device itself. Then the `localhost` link produced the credentials file as expected.

If you are not using 'google-oauthlib-tool` over an ssh connection and/or have the lite (headless) version of the raspberry pi OS installed, I assume something is probably wrong with the port adaptation to 8182.