# google-oauthlib-tool doesn't ask authorization code and has no '--headless' option on rpi-4B

Tags: python-3.x, google-api, google-oauth, raspberry-pi4, google-assistant-sdk

I'm trying to embed [google assistant SDK](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk) on my raspberry pi by following [this guide by Google](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/guides/service/python). However I'm stuck at configuring the Oauth2 credentials in the [generate credentials](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/guides/service/python/embed/install-sample#generate_credentials) step of the guide.

I installed the `google-auth-oauthlib[tool]` package to be able to run `google-oauthlib-tool`. When I run the ran the tool as explained in the guide, I get the following error:

```
$ google-oauthlib-tool --scope https://www.googleapis.com/auth/assistant-sdk-prototype \
      --save --headless --client-secrets /path/to/client_secret_client-id.json
Error: no such option: --headless
```

(PS. I adapted the --client-secrets path to the correct json file I downloaded from [google projects API credentials page](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials))

When I remove the `--headless` option from the command, the tool produces an authorization URL as expected. I can go to the URL, sign into my google account and activate the necessary permissions. Next, I get a google 'site unreachable' page as it is referring me to a URL starting with `localhost:8080/...`. From the full url I can extract the needed `4/...` code to finalize the authorization process... In theory as I then noticed the `google-oauthlib-tool` never asked me for the authorization code in the terminal. It just shows an **empty line** but it should say (according to [step 4](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/guides/service/python/embed/install-sample#generate_credentials)):

```
Enter the authorization code:
```

Does anyone know how why `google-oauthlib-tool` never asks the Authorization code? It might have something to do with the missing `--headless` option but I don't know enough about this whole Oauth2 process.

I've tried force-reinstalling all involved tools but that didn't solve the problem.

session info:

- python 3.9.2
- pip 23.0.1
- google-auth-oauthlib 1.0.0
- linux kernel: Linux 6.1.21-v8+ aarch64
- OS: Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)
- platform: Raspberry pi 4B

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my own question but I'll leave this post up for future reference.

**background:**
I went looking into around what 'headless' actually means (pretty basic for most of you probably). It refers to 'headless client', aka, an application/OS running without GUI (Graphic User Interface). Basically, only the command line.
Thus, I realized I installed the GUI version of the raspberry pi OS instead of the lite version. The google guide probably assumed I was running a headless client.

**solution:**
Instead of remote connecting to my raspberry pi over ssh, I directly opened the command line from the device itself through the GUI and ran the `google-oauthlib-tool` without the `--headless` option. Then the `localhost:8080/...` link worked and it created the credentials file on my device.

Answer (score 0):

Solution that worked for me with non-GUI raspberry PI:

- download screen "sudo apt-get screen"
- execute screen -S auth
- execute source env/bin/activate
- execute google-oauthlib-tool --scope 
  https://www.googleapis.com/auth/assistant-sdk-prototype --save --client-secrets /path/to/client_secret_client-id.json

Modify the command to match the secret file

- Complete authentication on any device using chrome
- At this state, you should see a failed to load website page
- open chrome dev tools(F12)
- go to network
- reload the webpage
- on the entry that popped up, click copy-> format curl(bash)
- on raspberry pi, press "Ctrl+a" and afterward "d" to close the screen
- paste in terminal